# Синхронизация между двумя локальными серверами

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, сервер, linux-mint

На одном компьютере у меня Linux Mint. На другом - Windows 10. На обоих крутятся локальные apache и mysql. До этого стояло две windows. т.к. работал на двух компьютерах, а отдельного сервера или облака не было, то вопрос cинхронизации решал в лоб - ставил xampp в папку dropbox и не знал проблем - все файлы синхронизировались на всех компах. Но как быть теперь - чёрт знает. Кто что подскажет? И если с синхронизацией файлов ещё ладно - можно разобраться, но как быть с базой данных mysql?

Comment: Синхронизация БД в системе из нескольких MySQL серверов описана в главе 29 "РАСПРЕДЕЛЕННЫЕ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ" книги Л. Аткинсона "MySQL БИБЛИОТЕКА ПРОФЕССИОНАЛА" В двух словах это не рассказать.